# Return is not returning values as expected

Tags: processing, rounding

I am trying to get the variable time (a float) rounded to the hundreth's place. (0.01, 0.02, ...)

```
float Time = 0.0;
float Time += 1/frameRate;

return( (round(Time*100)) /100);
```

This is what I attempted, but my results were rounded to the nearest integer (0.0, 1.0, ...)

Then I tried this instead:

```
float x = round(Time*100);
return(x/100);
```

and it worked. I solved my own issue, but I'm struggling to find out why it works while the other doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you look at [round documentation](https://processing.org/reference/round_.html), you can see that `round(x)` returns you an int.

So when you write `round(x)/100`, you are dividing an int by 100, causing unexpected behaviour.
But in `float x = round(y)`, you are explicitly typecasting it into float, so the division works as expected.